# R ggplot2 geom_point shapes

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I am working with `ggplot2` and want my `geom_points` to have individual shapes based on dataframe rows.

```
data <- read.csv(my_csv_path) # 
plot <- ggplot(data = data) + # in this file I have shape numbers (17 or 21) for each csv row.
 geom_point(aes(shape = shape), color = "grey20")
```

Each row has individial shape and I want to draw based on it. My output always draws triangles, based on csv file.

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will work with your data. If not, do paste a sample of the data using `dput`. `scale_shape_identity` applies the shape numbers from the dataframe:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

tibble(shape = 1:5, x = 1:5, y = 1) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y, shape = shape)) +
  geom_point(size = 10, colour = "grey20") +
  scale_shape_identity()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>